# Switching Multi-column to twoclumn research paper , create gap and start double on next page

Tags: floats, two-column, multicolumn, multicol

I have downloaded a template to write research paper. It is multi-column(two column) template,But due to multicolumn (Psuedocode and other tables) were not working on this template (Doesnt show anything, except text and picture).
I switched multicolumn to twocolumn document, pseudo and tables works now. But after abstract, introduction shows on next, After abstract whole page is blank, I am sharing picture and code.

[image]

Code is here below

```
\documentclass[multicolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,textcomp,marvosym,picins,amsmath,caption,threeparttable,amsthm,subfigure,float,lastpage,lscape,algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{eurosym,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,CJK,multicol,graphics,indentfirst,color,bm,upgreek,booktabs,graphicx,multirow,warpcol}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[noend]{algorithm}
%\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[lined,algonl,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\looseness=-1
%------------Page layout and margin and Headrule-------------
\headsep=5mm \headheight=4mm \topmargin=0cm \oddsidemargin=-0.5cm
\evensidemargin=-0.5cm \marginparwidth=0pt \marginparsep= 0pt
\marginparpush=0pt \textheight=23.1cm \textwidth=17.5cm \footskip=8mm
\columnsep=7mm \setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.1pt}
\footnotesep=3.5mm\arraycolsep=2pt
\font\tenrm=cmr10
%===========================================================
\def\footnoterule{\kern 1mm \hrule width 10cm \kern 2mm}
\def\rmd{{\rm d}} \def\rmi{{\rm i}} \def\rme{{\rm e}}
\def\sj#1{$^{[#1]}$}\def\lt{\left}\def\rt{\right}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\tablename{\bf \footnotesize Table}
\renewcommand\figurename{\footnotesize Fig.\!\!}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}%
\captionsetup[longtable]{labelsep=period}%
\allowdisplaybreaks
\sloppy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\catcode`@=11
\def\title#1{\vspace{3mm}\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.1cm\Large\bf\boldmath\protect\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.1pt #1
\end{flushleft}\vspace{1mm} }
\def\author#1{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize #1\end{flushleft}\vspace*{-4pt} \vspace{3mm}}
\def\address#1#2{\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.35cm${}^{#1}$\small\it #2\vglue-.35cm\end{flushleft}\vspace{-2mm}\par}
\def\jz#1#2{{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{\!\!$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$#2}}}
\catcode`@=11
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
 %{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex \@plus -.3ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2.2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=14.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex\@plus -.2ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-2.2ex\@plus -.21ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {1.4ex \@plus.2ex}
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\sl}}
\def\proofname{{\indent \it Proof.}}
%===========================================================���ϲ���

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% ����ҳüҳ��
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\sl Shortened Title Within 45 Characters}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\sl J. Comput. Sci. \& Technol.}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-13mm}
\noindent {\small Journal of computer science and technology: Instruction for authors.
JOURNAL OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY}
%===========================================================
\vspace*{2mm}

\title{AYATDROID: A Scalable Malware Detection Approach}

\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{{}\\[-4mm]\indent\ Regular Paper}

\noindent {\small\bf Abstract} \quad  {\small \textcolor{blue}{Please provide an abstract of 100 to 250 words. The abstract should clearly state the nature and significance of the paper. It must not include undefined abbreviations, mathematical expressions or bibliographic references.}}

\vspace*{3mm}
\noindent{\small\bf Keywords} \quad {\small keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword,
keyword [\textcolor{blue}{Keywords should closely reflect the topic and should optically
characterize the paper. Please use about 3$\sim $5 keywords or phrases in
alphabetical order separated by commas.}]}
\vspace*{4mm}
\end{CJK*}
\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.2pt
\parskip=0pt plus.2pt minus0.2pt
\begin{twocolumn}
\section{Introduction}
The Android Operating System is used on more than 2.8 billion smartphones. Only last year, over 1.05 billion Android phones were shipped. Among mobile phone users, over 75\% use Android smartphones due to their low prices and open-source operating systems, which make up the most popular operating system. Smartphones are no longer just for communications; they have evoloved into one of lifes necessities. An average person spends 5 to 6 hours daily on mobile devices, including browsing, social media, and online purchasing apps. The Android platform offers a free play store to download applications. 
\label{last-page}
\end{twocolumn}
\label{last-page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems, that you like to publish article to dome journal (Journal of computer science and technology?). Is this true, why you not simple use their templates.

Comment: Yes, I am using their template. But I can not add pseudo or other tables in their template, that maybe due to its multicolumn properties. I switched it to two column template, pseudo and tables work. But after abstract whole page become empty and introduction start from next page

Comment: What’s the difference to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651657/changing-from-single-column-to-two-columns-two-column-text-migrates-to-next-pag ?

Comment: Please see the the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Comment: Can you point to the green tickmark, Sorry I can not find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\begin{multicols}{2} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \section{Introduction}
        The Android Operating System is used on more than 2.8 billion smartphones. Only last year, over 1.05 billion Android phones were shipped. Among mobile phone users, over 75\% use Android smartphones due to their low prices and open-source operating systems, which make up the most popular operating system. Smartphones are no longer just for communications; they have evoloved into one of lifes necessities. An average person spends 5 to 6 hours daily on mobile devices, including browsing, social media, and online purchasing apps. The Android platform offers a free play store to download applications. 
        \label{last-page}
\end{multicols}
```

instead of `\begin{twocolumn}`  The package `multicol` is already loaded.

[image: b]

**UPDATE** after follow up question.

Its not possible to use floats inside the `multicols` environment.

Add the package `float` and use the forced --non float-- **H**.

[image: b]

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Introduction}

The Android Operating System is used on more than 2.8 billion smartphones. Only last year, over 1.05 billion Android phones were shipped. Among mobile phone users, over 75\% use Android smartphones due to their low prices and open-source operating systems, which make up the most popular operating system. Smartphones are no longer just for communications; they have evoloved into one of lifes necessities. An average person spends 5 to 6 hours daily on mobile devices, including browsing, social media, and online purchasing apps. The Android platform offers a free play store to download applications. 


\begin{algorithm}[H]   
\caption{Clone Detection}\label{alg:Clone}  
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Clone Detection}{$a,b$}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
        \State \textbf{return} $b$
        \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

The improved Paillier Cryptosystem for a secured data transmission is seen in the Table \ref{tab:PCS}.

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{A table}\label{tab:PCS}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        A& B\\
        C& D
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table} 

Some text.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
    
    Among mobile phone users, over 75\% use Android smartphones due to their low prices and open-source operating systems, which make up the most popular operating system. The     Algorithm \ref{alg:Clone} provides a method to detect clones.   

\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Simon Dispa. The problem is still right there. This template comes with {multicols}{2}, But tables and algorithms don't work in {multicols}, Whenever I write code, algorithms and table don't show in pdf. It only shows text and pictures. But when I change {multicols} to {twocols}, algorithms and tables successfully execute and show in pdf. But then Introduction start from next page after abstact

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bClao.png

Comment: Thank you so much, you have saved me from a lot of headaches. You are pro, bro