# Changing From Single Column To Two Columns, Two column text migrates to next page. How can I force it to stay together?

Tags: two-column, multicolumn, multicol, document

This is my first time using latex, and I run into the problem of columns.
How can I remove gap between 1 column and 2 columns.
Please have a look at picture.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lswTk.jpg

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,textcomp,marvosym,picins,amsmath,caption,threeparttable,amsthm,subfigure,float,lastpage,lscape}
\usepackage{eurosym,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,CJK,multicol,graphics,indentfirst,color,bm,upgreek,booktabs,graphicx,multirow,warpcol}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{cite}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}    
\newcommand{\WRP}{\par\qquad\(\hookrightarrow\)\enspace}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}



\looseness=-1
%------------Page layout and margin and Headrule-------------
\headsep=5mm \headheight=4mm \topmargin=0cm \oddsidemargin=-0.5cm
\evensidemargin=-0.5cm \marginparwidth=0pt \marginparsep= 0pt
\marginparpush=0pt \textheight=23.1cm \textwidth=17.5cm \footskip=8mm
\columnsep=7mm \setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.1pt}
\footnotesep=3.5mm\arraycolsep=2pt
\font\tenrm=cmr10
%===========================================================
\def\footnoterule{\kern 1mm \hrule width 10cm \kern 2mm}
\def\rmd{{\rm d}} \def\rmi{{\rm i}} \def\rme{{\rm e}}
\def\sj#1{$^{[#1]}$}\def\lt{\left}\def\rt{\right}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\tablename{\bf \footnotesize Table}
\renewcommand\figurename{\footnotesize Fig.\!\!}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}%
\captionsetup[longtable]{labelsep=period}%
\allowdisplaybreaks
\sloppy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\catcode`@=11
\def\title#1{\vspace{3mm}\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.1cm\Large\bf\boldmath\protect\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.1pt #1
\end{flushleft}\vspace{1mm} }
\def\author#1{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize #1\end{flushleft}\vspace*{-4pt} \vspace{3mm}}
\def\address#1#2{\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.35cm${}^{#1}$\small\it #2\vglue-.35cm\end{flushleft}\vspace{-2mm}\par}
\def\jz#1#2{{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{\!\!$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$#2}}}
\catcode`@=11
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
 %{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex \@plus -.3ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2.2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=14.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex\@plus -.2ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-2.2ex\@plus -.21ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {1.4ex \@plus.2ex}
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\sl}}
\def\proofname{{\indent \it Proof.}}
%===========================================================���ϲ���

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% ����ҳüҳ��
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\sl Shortened Title Within 45 Characters}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\sl J. Comput. Sci. \& Technol.}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-13mm}
\noindent {\small Journal of computer science and technology: Instruction for authors.
JOURNAL OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY}
%===========================================================
\vspace*{2mm}

\title{Journal of Computer Science and Technology: Instruction for Authors}

\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{{}\\[-4mm]\indent\ Regular Paper}

\noindent {\small\bf Abstract} \quad  {\small \textcolor{black}{In this paper, we present an improved Paillier Cryptosystem for a secured data transmission based on the Residue Number System (RNS). , a high level resistance to key sensitivity attacks, and an acceptable level of resilience. In terms of security, it has been discovered that the proposed system outperforms the present algorithm.}}

\vspace*{3mm}

\noindent{\small\bf Keywords} \quad {\small Android software, Code cloning, Malware code Detection, Mobile security, Malware detection, Software reuse, Android apps re-usability.}

\vspace*{4mm}

\end{CJK*}
\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.2pt
\parskip=0pt plus.2pt minus0.2pt
\begin{twocolumn}

\section{Introduction}

The Android Operating System is used on more than 2.8 billion smartphones. Only last year, over 1.05 billion Android phones were shipped. Among mobile phone users, over 75\% use Android smartphones due to their low prices and open-source operating systems, which make up the most popular operating system
\label{last-page}
\end{twocolumn}
\label{last-page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please Edit your question and show relevant code: 1) We can copy and compile it, so start with \documentclass. 2) It shows your problem, so discard anything, that's not needed. 3) For shorter code you may want to use packages lipsum or blindtext, like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604917/blindtext-vs-lipsum .

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I am trying to solve this issue from last 3 days. I have included source code, If you can please have a look at the code.

Comment: Welcome! This is a very complex (and scary)  preamble. It has things (`\rm`?) that are deprecated since 1990 or earlier. But the most important thing is: that it does not compile without errors. When you have even one error in compiling, the PDF is basically GiGo --- Garbage in, Garbage out.

Comment: @YasirGlani, referring to Rmano’s comment: is this a current template you are using? Where does it come from? If it’s for a journal: don’t they provide one?

Comment: @MS-SPO. They did provide the template, it is a multi-column template(basically two columns). But whenever i write pseudo code algorithm or tables, it does not compile in pdf(only text and images are shown). So I changed it to two column, pseudo code and table are showing in pdf now, but it created gap between abstract and introduction(1 column to 2 column.)

Comment: Ok, if THAT’s their official template … what are you allowed to change? Only content, or also the “scary” preamble?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is one way to do it.

**Analysis**: Two steps:

- step 1: I disabled ALL packages, and next included those, which lets the file compile
- step 2: I had a closer look into the `twocolumn` issue

**Speculation**: You may have puzzled the `twocolumn` layout from class `article`, which perhaps requires, i.e. inserts, a new page. There is also a `\twocolumn` statement, but I didn't dig into its correct use.

**Solution**:

- `\usepackage{multicol}`
- `\begin{multicols}{2}{ .. your text ..}\end{multicols}`
- in the code below check for comments with `%<<<` at the end of a line
- using environment `minipage` instead might do the same job

For demonstration purposes I included package `lipsum`, just to output some text.

**Result**:
[image: result]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% DISABLED most packages AND included those relevant here to compile
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cjk}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to fill in more text
\usepackage{multicol}% <<<
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,textcomp,marvosym}
%%\usepackage{picins} % not found
%\usepackage{amsmath,caption,threeparttable,amsthm,subfigure,float,lastpage,lscape}
%\usepackage{eurosym,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,CJK,multicol,graphics,indentfirst,color,bm,upgreek,booktabs,graphicx,multirow,warpcol}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{smartdiagram}
%\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{venndiagram}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{booktabs}

%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}    
\newcommand{\WRP}{\par\qquad\(\hookrightarrow\)\enspace}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}



\looseness=-1
%------------Page layout and margin and Headrule-------------
\headsep=5mm \headheight=4mm \topmargin=0cm \oddsidemargin=-0.5cm
\evensidemargin=-0.5cm \marginparwidth=0pt \marginparsep= 0pt
\marginparpush=0pt \textheight=23.1cm \textwidth=17.5cm \footskip=8mm
\columnsep=7mm \setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.1pt}
\footnotesep=3.5mm\arraycolsep=2pt
\font\tenrm=cmr10
%===========================================================
\def\footnoterule{\kern 1mm \hrule width 10cm \kern 2mm}
\def\rmd{{\rm d}} \def\rmi{{\rm i}} \def\rme{{\rm e}}
\def\sj#1{$^{[#1]}$}\def\lt{\left}\def\rt{\right}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\tablename{\bf \footnotesize Table}
\renewcommand\figurename{\footnotesize Fig.\!\!}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}%
\captionsetup[longtable]{labelsep=period}%
\allowdisplaybreaks
\sloppy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\catcode`@=11
\def\title#1{\vspace{3mm}\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.1cm\Large\bf\boldmath\protect\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.1pt #1
\end{flushleft}\vspace{1mm} }
\def\author#1{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize #1\end{flushleft}\vspace*{-4pt} \vspace{3mm}}
\def\address#1#2{\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.35cm${}^{#1}$\small\it #2\vglue-.35cm\end{flushleft}\vspace{-2mm}\par}
\def\jz#1#2{{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{\!\!$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$#2}}}
\catcode`@=11
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
 %{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex \@plus -.3ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2.2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=14.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex\@plus -.2ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-2.2ex\@plus -.21ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {1.4ex \@plus.2ex}
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\sl}}
\def\proofname{{\indent \it Proof.}}
%===========================================================���ϲ���

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% ����ҳüҳ��
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\sl Shortened Title Within 45 Characters}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\sl J. Comput. Sci. \& Technol.}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\begin{document}
    \begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \vspace*{-13mm}
        \noindent {\small Journal of computer science and   technology: Instruction for authors.
JOURNAL OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY}
%===========================================================
        \vspace*{2mm}

        \title{Journal of Computer Science and Technology: Instruction for Authors}

        \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{{}\\[-4mm]\indent\ Regular Paper}

        \noindent {\small\bf Abstract} \quad  {\small \textcolor{black}{In this paper, we present an improved Paillier Cryptosystem for a secured data transmission based on the Residue Number System (RNS). , a high level resistance to key sensitivity attacks, and an acceptable level of resilience. In terms of security, it has been discovered that the proposed system outperforms the present algorithm.}}


        \vspace*{3mm}

        \noindent{\small\bf Keywords} \quad {\small Android software, Code cloning, Malware code Detection, Mobile security, Malware detection, Software reuse, Android apps re-usability.}

        \vspace*{4mm}

    \end{CJK*}
    
\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.2pt
\parskip=0pt plus.2pt minus0.2pt


%\begin{twocolumn}
\begin{multicols}{2}% <<<
    \section{Introduction}

    The Android Operating System is used on more than 2.8 billion smartphones. Only last year, over 1.05 billion Android phones were shipped. Among mobile phone users, over 75\% use Android smartphones due to their low prices and open-source operating systems, which make up the most popular operating system.

    \lipsum[1]% just some dummy text
\end{multicols}
%\end{twocolumn}

    \lipsum[2]% just some dummy text
    \label{last-page}


\label{last-page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Problem is still there, I can not add Algorithms and tables in {multicols}{2}. Whenever I include, algorithms and tables doesnt show in pdf. Can you try to add algorithm{pseudocode} in this template. Again thank you much.

Comment: Please have a loot at this screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bClao.png

Comment: I can have a look later. // I suggest to Edit your question and add your remarks from the comments on two- and multicolumns, and the algorithm problem in a prominent place.

Answer (score 1):

Using the template from [JCST Publish Template (Latex)](https://mc03.manuscriptcentral.com/societyimages/jcst/JCST-Template-Publish%20Latex.rar)  unchanged since it loads the package `multicol`.

and this document (use `\begin{multicols}{2}` !!)

```
\begin{document}
    
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{-13mm}
    \noindent {\small Journal of computer science and technology: Instruction for authors.
    JOURNAL OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY}
    %===========================================================
    \vspace*{2mm}
    
    \title{Journal of Computer Science and Technology: Instruction for Authors}
    
    \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{{}\\[-4mm]\indent\ Regular Paper}
    
    \noindent {\small\bf Abstract} \quad  {\small \textcolor{black}{In this paper, we present an improved Paillier Cryptosystem for a secured data transmission based on the Residue Number System (RNS). , a high level resistance to key sensitivity attacks, and an acceptable level of resilience. In terms of security, it has been discovered that the proposed system outperforms the present algorithm.}}
    
    \vspace*{3mm}
    
    \noindent{\small\bf Keywords} \quad {\small Android software, Code cloning, Malware code Detection, Mobile security, Malware detection, Software reuse, Android apps re-usability.}
    
    \vspace*{4mm}


\end{CJK*}
    \baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.2pt
    \parskip=0pt plus.2pt minus0.2pt

\begin{multicols}{2}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \section{Introduction}
        
        The Android Operating System is used on more than 2.8 billion smartphones. Only last year, over 1.05 billion Android phones were shipped. Among mobile phone users, over 75\% use Android smartphones due to their low prices and open-source operating systems, which make up the most popular operating system            
        
\end{multicols}
    \label{last-page}
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you @Simon Dispa. Algorithms and tables does not work in {multicols} template. The original template comes with {multicols}, I changed it to {twocolumns}, then algorithms(pseudo code) and tables works, but then it create gap and started introduction on next page.

Comment: Please have a look at this screenshot.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bClao.png

Answer (score 1):

This answer contains:

- some background for a LaTeX novice
- making the JCST-template compile
- filling it with some demo-content, with both blindtext and text
- final suggestions

[image: example with two algorithms]

### Background for a LaTeX novice

As you wrote, this is your first LaTeX experience. LaTeX can be puzzling in the beginning. From layout-oriented programs like *MS-Word*, *Adobe Acrobat*, *Framemaker* or *Scribus* one is kind of pre-trained to work both on content (what to say) AND layout (where to place what) at the same time.

LaTeX differs: make your say (text), and it will put things "neatly", where it finds space. That was the initial idea. Now, authors like to impact every now and then on placement. That's why environments (like figure) provide some placement suggestions to LaTeX. Dedicated packages go even a step further.

**As a strategy**, try working in the JCST's template world. Rely on "that's what they want it to look like in print".

If you haven't done yet, I suggest to get some book on LaTeX introduction, or glimpse through and search inside [wikibooks on LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Introduction). You can find even more hints on introductory material on this site.

And it's always a good idea to look up a package on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)  and read its [manual](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).

### Making the JCST template compile

So to answer your questions about **gaps** and **algorithms** my first step was to download the JCST-template from the link you gave and make it compile. It's also a bit different in the preamble from your initially posted code. There were some minor problems making it compile.

As a general rule, search for *MS-SPO* in the code, below, which I put with my comments there.

`picins` (1991) seems to be outdated. It will be used e.g. for including authors fotos at the end. I excluded it. Also package `picinpar` doesn't work (\hsize error). So probably you can leave this to JCST's release, unless you plan to include further images in your content.

Packages `algorithm` and `algoritmic` don't seem to exist on CTAN anymore. Though my distributions console is trying to install them, I decided to go with `algorithm2e`, with the options they provide. Strongly recomment do check its use and options in the manual.

Package `lipsum` is just to fill in some blind text for demonstration purposes.

By intention I left all that content about authors, keywords etc., as your accepted paper will consume this space as well, later. Same for the (adjusted) footer.

### Content example

You will see, I deleted the content (just those parts) from the JCST-template. I used `\section{}` and `\subsection{}` to provide a basic structure for this demo-content.

For "1 Introduction" I just placed a few `\lipsum` statements AND inserted an algorithm, copied from the [manual](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf):

- first version with option [H] (place here (if possible))
- second version no option, i.e. letting it float (it will move around when you vary your content)

Besides that I put a `\label{}` inside both `\caption` statements, so you can refer to the algorithms in text later. A few things about this:

- naming is free; I decided to use `alg:N`, where N is a digit; a name might be even better, e.g. `alg:someHint`
- LaTeX will take care of numbering itself, that's why using `alg:N` might be puzzling over time and `alg:Name` might be better
- you don't have to follow this scheme, but it helps you to avoid mistakes; see e.g. `tab:anOverview`, `fig:aNiceCurve` etc. while your content grows

To refer to these labels, use `\ref{}` in running text. See "2 Details" for details for an example, both in print and code. E.g. you could refer to a table later as `\ref{tab:anOverview}`, and LaTeX will replace it by the correct numer of the table during compile.

Be aware, that LaTeX needs two compile runs to place the correct values there (1st run: compile, 2nd run: replace what was found).

From the screenshot you can see some characteristics:

- p. 2 "by chance" the floating algorithm is where you put it; it may move around
- LaTeX placement algorithms balanced both (unfinished) columns "nicely", which will change when you edit more

Again, check the [manual of algorithm2e](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), which tells you how to handle e.g.:

- longer algos
- "page break"
- a-col, 2-col spans
- when to use `\;` in a line of pseudocode
- etc.

### Final suggestions

Copy my code AND replace my content with yours (*% ~~~ MS-SPO: here starts YOUR content ~~~~~~~~~~*). Don't care about the rest, and allow things to float around for the moment. Gaps will come and go as you edit. Focus on your content and do "placement" adjustments, once you are almost finished.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,textcomp,marvosym}
%,picins,% MS-SPO: outdated (from 1991)
%\usepackage{picinpar} % MS-SPO: doesn't solve the problems with author-images at the end
\usepackage{amsmath,caption,threeparttable,amsthm,subfigure}
\usepackage{eurosym,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,CJK,multicol,graphics,indentfirst,color,bm,upgreek,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[noend]{algorithm}% MS-SPO: not on CTAN, though your distributions console might install it
%\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}% MS-SPO: same
\usepackage[lined,algonl,boxed]{algorithm2e} % MS-SPO: prefer this one, can be found on CTAN
\usepackage{lipsum}% MS-SPO: just to enter some blindtext
%\looseness=-1
%------------Page layout and margin and Headrule-------------
\headsep=5mm \headheight=4mm \topmargin=-.8cm \oddsidemargin=-.8cm
\evensidemargin=-.8cm \marginparwidth=0pt \marginparsep= 0pt
\marginparpush=0pt \textheight=23.1cm \textwidth=17.5cm \footskip=8mm
\columnsep=7mm \setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnotesep=3.5mm\arraycolsep=2pt
\font\tenrm=cmr10
%===========================================================
\def\footnoterule{\kern 1mm \hrule width 10cm \kern 2mm}
\def\rmd{{\rm d}} \def\rmi{{\rm i}} \def\rme{{\rm e}}
\def\sj#1{$^{[#1]}$}\def\lt{\left}\def\rt{\right}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\tablename{\bf \footnotesize Table}
\renewcommand\figurename{\footnotesize Fig.\!\!}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}%
\captionsetup[longtable]{labelsep=period}%
\allowdisplaybreaks
\sloppy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\catcode`@=11
\def\title#1{\vspace{3mm}\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.1cm\Large\bf\boldmath\protect\baselineskip=18pt plus.2pt minus.1pt #1
\end{flushleft}\vspace{1mm} }
\def\author#1{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize #1\end{flushleft}\vspace*{-4pt} \vspace{3mm}}
\def\address#1#2{\begin{flushleft}\vglue-.35cm${}^{#1}$\small\it #2\vglue-.35cm\end{flushleft}\vspace{-2mm}\par}
\def\jz#1#2{{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$\footnotetext{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny #1}}$#2}}}
\def\jzd#1#2{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny{#1}}}$\footnotetext{$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny{#1}}}$#2}}
\catcode`@=11
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
 %{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex \@plus -.3ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2.2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=14.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-3ex\@plus -.2ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {2ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12.5pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\bfseries}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
 %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {-2.2ex\@plus -.21ex \@minus -.2ex}%
 {1.4ex \@plus.2ex}
{\normalfont\normalsize\protect\baselineskip=12pt plus.2pt minus.2pt\sl}}
\def\proofname{{\indent \it Proof.}}
%===========================================================以上不动

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% 清空页眉页脚
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\sl First Author {\it et al.}: Shortened Title Within 45 Characters}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\sl J. Comput. Sci. \& Technol., January 2018,
Vol., No.}
\setcounter{page}{1}

% ~~~ MS-SPO: here starts content, kind of standardized ~~~
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-13mm}
\noindent {\small First Author, Second Author, Third
Author {\it et al.} Journal of computer science and technology: Instruction for authors.
JOURNAL OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY \ 33(1): \thepage--\pageref{last-page}
\ January 2018. DOI 10.1007/s11390-015-0000-0}
%===========================================================
\vspace*{2mm}

\title{Journal of Computer Science and Technology: Instruction for Authors}

\author{First Author[\textcolor{blue}{First-Name Surname}]$^{1,2,*}$ (Chinese Name, if available), Second Author$^{1}$ (Chinese Name, if available), and Third Author$^{2}$ (Chinese Name, if available)}

\address{1}{Institute of Computing Technology, Chinese Academy of Sciences, Beijing 100190, China}
\address{2}{[\textcolor{blue}{Affiliation, City Postcode, Country}]}

\vspace{2mm}

\noindent E-mail: ***@*********; ***@********* [\textcolor{blue}{Please list the emails of all the authors in order. The domain names of the e-mails should correspond to the authors' affiliations, and any free personal e-mail, e.g., qq.com, 126.com, 163.com, gmail.com, hotmail.com, is not permitted}]\\[-1mm]

\noindent Received July 15, 2018 [\textcolor{blue}{Month Day, Year}]; accepted October 14, 2018 [\textcolor{blue}{Month Day, Year}].\\[1mm]

\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{{}\\[-4mm]\indent\ Regular Paper\\[.5mm]
%\indent\quad Special Section of CAD/Graphcis 2017\\[.5mm]
%\indent\quad  A preliminary version of the paper was published in SMP 2014.\\[.5mm]
\indent\ by the National Natural Science Foundation of China under Grant Nos.~******** and ********, the National High Technology Research and Development 863 Program of China under Grant No.~********, the National Basic Research 973 Program of China under Grant No.~********, and the Natural Science Foundation of Shandong Province of China under Grant No.~*******. \\[.5mm]
\indent\ $^*$Corresponding Author
\\[1.2mm]\indent\ %$^{\footnotesize\textcircled{\tiny1}}$https://jcst.ict.ac.cn/EN/column/column107.shtml, May 2020.% not needed
\\[.5mm]\indent\ \copyright Institute of Computing Technology, Chinese Academy of Sciences 2021}

\noindent {\small\bf Abstract} \quad  {\small \textcolor{blue}{Please provide an abstract of 100 to 250 words. The abstract should clearly state the nature and significance of the paper. It must not include undefined abbreviations, mathematical expressions or bibliographic references.}}

\vspace*{3mm}

\noindent{\small\bf Keywords} \quad {\small keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword,
keyword [\textcolor{blue}{Keywords should closely reflect the topic and should optically
characterize the paper. Please use about 3$\sim $5 keywords or phrases in
alphabetical order separated by commas.}]}

\vspace*{4mm}

\end{CJK*}
\baselineskip=15.8pt plus.2pt minus.2pt
\parskip=0pt plus.2pt minus0.2pt
\begin{multicols}{2}
% ~~~ MS-SPO: here starts YOUR content ~~~~~~~~~~

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[H]% MS-SPO: copied from manual
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
        read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
        go to next section\;
    current section becomes this one\;
    }{
        go back to the beginning of current section\;
        }
    }
    \caption{\label{alg:1}How to write algorithms, option [H] = here}% MS-SPO: put label, if you want to reference it from text
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]


\begin{algorithm}[H]% MS-SPO: copied from manual
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
        read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
        go to next section\;
    current section becomes this one\;
    }{
        go back to the beginning of current section\;
        }
    }
    \caption{\label{alg:2}How to write algorithms, no option = float}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Details}

Here ist how you can reference Algorithms \ref{alg:1} and \ref{alg:2} in running text. \ref{alg:1} is tried to put HERE, while \ref{alg:2} will appear where \LaTeX{} finds enough space, so you may find it being shifted around as your content varies from editing.


\subsection{Some details}


\subsection{Even more details}


\section{Summary}


% ~~~ MS-SPO: here ends YOUR content ~~~~~~~~~~
\label{last-page}
\end{multicols}
\label{last-page}
\end{document}
```